# Getting error “ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h” file not found

Tags: cocoapods, reactive-cocoa

I'm developing an app using Xcode 6 and cocoa pods.

But it is showing an lexical or preprocessor issue:

> “ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h” file not found.

I installed cocoa pods and also updated it. Anyone please suggest how to solve this issue.

Comment: please show some code that you've tried so far

Comment: @Vikrant      / /@import CoreLocation;
#import <ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h>
//@import Foundation;

//@interface WXClient : NSObject
- (RACSignal *)fetchJSONFromURL:(NSURL *)url;
- (RACSignal *)fetchCurrentConditionsForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
- (RACSignal *)fetchHourlyForecastForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
- (RACSignal *)fetchDailyForecastForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble installing RAC my first time around, and here's what I usually go through if I'm getting CocoaPods errors :

1 : Check if the `Build Active Architecture Only` option is set to `NO` for debug builds. Go to the `Pods` project in your workspace, make sure `Pods` is selected and not one of the targets on the inner left side panel, and then search for `Build Active Architecture Only` and set it to `NO`. Try rebuilding/cleaning again after.

[image: build active architecture only]

2 : Make sure you're passing in `-all_load` to `Other linker flags` in your target build settings. (Select project > Go to your target > `Search for`Other linker flags`> Add`-all_load`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Yusef Napora's version of ReactiveCocoa 2 in a swift project :

1. -BridgingHeader.h set in build settings and containing the import to < ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h >
2. Linked Frameworks and Libraries: + libReactiveCocoa-iOS.a
3. Library Search Paths : + < yourPath >/ReactiveCocoaFramework/build/Debug-iphoneos
4. Header Search Paths  : + $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../include
5. Compile. :)